# I need required fields on embed Mailchimp form on Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, mailchimp

I got an embed formulary in my Wordpress page. This is the code:

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
<h3 style="text-align: center;"><strong>PARA OBTENER TU EBOOK GRATIS</strong></h3>
<h3 style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="color: #808080;">Solamente indícame a dónde enviártelo, acompañado de tu nombre. </span></strong></h3>
<div class="mc-field-group" style="text-align: center;"><input id="mce-EMAIL" class="required email" height="50" name="EMAIL" required="" size="40%" type="email" value="" placeholder="Correo Electrónico" /></div>
<div class="mc-field-group" style="text-align: center;"></div>
<div class="mc-field-group" style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #808080;"><input id="mce-FNAME" class="" height="50" name="FNAME" required="" size="40%" type="text" value="" placeholder="Nombre" /></span></div>
<div class="mc-field-group" style="text-align: center;"></div>
<div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px; text-align: center;"><span style="color: #808080;"><input tabindex="-1" name="b_0b415a9fca1ed9cc7caa54c32_aa090c6422" type="text" value="" /></span></div>
<div class="clear" style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #808080;"><input id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" onClick="iAmAttilasEvent();"  name="subscribe" required="" size="40%" type="submit" value="Quiero mi Ebook Gratis" placeholder="Nombre" /></span></div>
</div>
</form></div>
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

I want my fields EMAIL and FNAME to be required to fill, so if they aren't, you can't press the subscribe button and it won't send you to any other site, but instead it will show a little text in the fields, telling you that you haven't provided your name or email.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as though you've already achieved your objective. You're using the required attribute on the email / name inputs which should prevent the form from being submitted when those fields are empty.

Comment: Yeah the required attribute its ok, but when suscribe button is clicked it sends u to another mailchimp page outside my web with another formulary (more extense). When i want to keep the users in the same page with the same embed formulary until they complete all the fields

Comment: OH! THat's the submit page. You have to change that in the process part inside your account. Typically I just have the html send you back to the page. Or you could use the API.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the **ADVANCED MODE** of your email signup process.

Here's how you can do that:

1) go to your Mailchimp account and then to `LISTS`

2) Select the list that this form is for.

3) Go to `Signup Forms` in the subnav.

4) Go to `General Forms` and scroll down to the bottom. There is something that says *Create completely customized forms, or code everything from scratch in advanced mode.*

5) Select *advanced mode* - now you will see all of the process steps.

6) select `Signup thank you page` and add the meta below INTO THE DOCUMENT HEAD and save it.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://THE PAGE YOU WANT THEM TO GO TO'" />
```

This is the easiest way to create the effect that you would like. If you want to NOT do this, I suggest using Mailchimp's API. [Here's a great tutorial](https://rudrastyh.com/api/mailchimp-subscription.html).